# Entity Framework UnitOfWork Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-of-work

I'm using EF UnitOfWorkPattern, is it a nice way to use one repository in another? For example, I have repository A, this repository needs logic to retrieve data from repository B.

Comment: This should be done at the service level where you can retrieve data from more than one repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say no. Repositories usually abstract away the CRUD operations, and nothing more. They are usually specific to one "entity" or "table".

If you need a functionality that goes "across repositories", then you are probably implementing some business logic, which is not part of the repository-uow layer.

Comment: My understanding is that, with UnitOfWork pattern the repositories will not have their own context objects, instead will use one context object to keep everything in one transaction. So, going by this, accessing a repository class from another repository will not be an issue.

Comment: It can be done. Since the context is the same for every repository and uow, it can work. But this is not how the pattern was designed. Repositories abstract away the CRUD operations per entity, the UOW manages the repositories and provides transactional behavior, which is in turn used from your "services" or "managers" or whatever you call your BLL components.

Comment: Agreed. Yes, repository should not have any business logic (that requires accessing another repository or entity.

Comment: I have projects listed below: 
1) Project.Core - here are interfaces of Repositories and Unit Of Work 
2) Project.DAL  - Here are all implementations of Core project
3) Project.Model - here are entities.
I'm going to build WCF service so i have to put my business logic in Service Project right?

Comment: I would create a separate project for the business logic (just a simple class library) and then reference this project form the WCF service project.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much